# Rails 5 - Render 2 different post orders on different URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm sure this is simple but I'm super new to Rails and just can't find the answer from googling.

I have a posts model by default that will be sorted by a custom algorithm (currently sorted by asc). I also want to create another view where it's sorted by newest under **mydomain.com/recent**

I don't want this done via ajax or anything. I just want the ability to show different views on separate url paths.

**posts_controller.erb**

```
 def index
   @posts = Post.order('created_at ASC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.js
   end
 end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= render @links %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use scopes in the model and parameters in the controller.

For example if your model had a scope like:

```
class Post
  # Move current controller custom order to scope
  scope :my_custom_order, -> { order(created_at: :asc }
  scope :recent_order, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
end
```

And if you made the `/recent` part of your URL an optional parameter in your routes.rb file like:

```
scope '(:order)' do
  # Do all your routes to route to PostsController in here
end
```

Then in your controller you could use that to determine your order for posts, and default back to your custom order for it:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.send(order).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end

private

def order
  :"#{params[:order] || 'my_custom'}_order"
end
```

Something along those lines with some tweaks to make it work exactly for your project should get you started on what you want to achieve.